# How can I emulate a MAG 254 (IPTV BOX) in software

Tags: iptv

I have an IP TV subscription that works well on a MAG 254 device. The service is locked to the boxes MAC address.

I would like to watch IPTV on my laptop too, however the provider only supports MAG 254 devices.

I want to be able to watch TV on my laptop and on my TV (not at the same time) and was wondering if anyone has done something to emulate a MAG 254 in Windows/linux or OSX.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried stbemu and yasem but they didn't work for me. Eventually, what did work was Kodi with the Stalker Client addon (the addon is pre-installed with Kodi).

Look for that addon inside Kodi, configure it to add your Portal URL, your MAC, your serial number and device ID (I think the device ID can be whichever 6 random numbers).

Then go to Settings and Live TV and enable it. Hopefully you will get a message that Kodi is downloading channels list and EPG info.

Comment: How would I get the necessary DeviceID1 and DeviceID2 and token info to fill in the settings section ?

Comment: For me, I just generated two 6 number Device IDs, out of my head. So just type two random ones, but make sure the length is 6 digits and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try **stbemu** for android (use **bluestacks** emulator if on Windows) or a windows application called **yasem**.

Tried both, stbemu wouldn't load my portal, but yasem did load it but I was unable to see any video (probably codecs issue).

Maybe one of them will work for you.

Comment: I tried stbemu and yasem. Same result for me. no video. I was not sure if it was the MAC/serial# that I had to pull of the MAG254, but I believe its not emulating as it should.